# Case & When no Select

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    c2.quantidade AS qtde_solicitada,

IF (
    (
        SUM(c1.quantidade) - c2.quantidade
    ) < 0,
    '0',
    c2.quantidade
) AS estoque,
 (
    SELECT
        SUM(quantidade_autorizada)
    FROM
        ferramental_requisicao
    WHERE
        devolvido = 1
) AS devolvido,

IF (
    c2.quantidade <= devolvido,
    'ferramental_estoque',
    'ferramental_requisicao'
) AS tabela,
 CASE
WHEN tabela = 'ferramental_requisicao' THEN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            ferramental_requisicao
        WHERE
            id_ativo_externo = c1.id_ativo_externo
        AND devolvido = 1
    )
ELSE
    'pare aqui'
END AS retorno
FROM
    ferramental_estoque AS c1
JOIN ferramental_requisicao AS c2 ON c2.id_ativo_externo = c1.id_ativo_externo
```

> Erro: coluna `tabela` não existe

Como eu posso adequar?

Comment: não pode fazer um case com um alias do mesmo select, nesse caso "tabela", precisar fazer o select separado para usar isso, e usar `WITH`

Comment: @RicardoPontual você consegue postar uma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão seria vc adequar uma os dados conforme a necessidade, gerando esses atributos dentro do `FROM` para ser consumida em outro nivel, um exemplo seria assim,

```
SELECT
c3.qtde_solicitada,
c3.estoque,
c3.devolvido,
c3.tabela,
CASE
WHEN c3.tabela = 'ferramental_requisicao' THEN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            ferramental_requisicao
        WHERE
            id_ativo_externo = c3.id_ativo_externo
        AND devolvido = 1
    )
ELSE
    'pare aqui'
END AS retorno
FROM (
    SELECT
        c2.quantidade AS qtde_solicitada,
        c1.id_ativo_externo
    IF (
        (
            SUM(c1.quantidade) - c2.quantidade
        ) < 0,
        '0',
        c2.quantidade
    ) AS estoque,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(quantidade_autorizada)
        FROM
            ferramental_requisicao
        WHERE
            devolvido = 1
    ) AS devolvido,

    IF (
        c2.quantidade <= devolvido,
        'ferramental_estoque',
        'ferramental_requisicao'
    ) AS tabela,

    FROM
        ferramental_estoque AS c1
    JOIN ferramental_requisicao AS c2 ON c2.id_ativo_externo = c1.id_ativo_externo
) as c3;
```

Como não tenho a base de dados não posso garantir que funcione, mas essa seria a ideia